# Firebug shows posted JSON data using AJAX, but PHP says $_POST is empty

Tags: php, ajax, json, post

I'm trying to finish up my first AJAX exchange, but I'm coming unstuck on the home stretch. I've got a JSON string which I'm sending via AJAX to a php page, `verify.php`, but when I try and receive this data, `$_POST` at `verify.php` seems to be totally empty, as indicated by the code on my `verify.php` page:

```
if (empty($_POST)) {
   echo 'empty';
} else {
   echo 'not-empty';
}
```

I have no clue why this is... my AJAX code seems to be okay:

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: 'serverside/verify.php',
   data: data, // Where data is a javascript obj. which has been JSON.stringify'ied. 
   dataType: "JSON",
   success: function(returned) {
      console.log(returned);
   }                
});
```

And I'm when I console.log my JSON string, I'm seeing it being shown fine, and even my success callback function is logging 'empty' to the console (because it's echoing 'empty' due to my if statement above). So the exchange seems to taking place fine, the data seems to be being sent fine, but it's obviously not arriving in the `$_POST` superglobal. Can anyone explain why?

Comment: Please, attach firebug screenshot! I think PHP is OK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check whether you have missed any step!

// Declare a variable

```
   var jsonObj = {demo: 'this is just a simple json object'}
```

// Lets convert our JSON object

```
   var postData = JSON.stringify(jsonObj);
```

// Lets put our stringified json into a variable for posting

```
   var postArray = {json:postData};

 $.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: "http://somedomain.local.com/phpfile.php",
   data: postArray,
   success: function(data){
      // Do some action here with the data variable that contains the resulting message
   }
 });
```

we need to strip the slashes out of the string which were put in for transport. Then we just run the json_decode php function. After that we can access the php object and use it however we like.

```
  if(isset($_POST["json"])){
    $json = stripslashes($_POST["json"]);
    $output = json_decode($json);

    // Now you can access your php object like so
    // $output[0]->variable-name
  }
```

Hope it will help!

Comment: dataType - The type of data that you're expecting back from the server. See manual http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Sorry, I distilled the question for simplicity. The URL's are correct.